# Jquery, FadeIn before unload

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to accomplish a transition effect if you will. On doc ready div fades out, the problem im having is when a visitor navigates away from the page (or .unload) I want the div to fade back in.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#overlay').fadeOut(2000, 'easeOutQuad');

});


$(window).beforeunload(function() {

    $('#overlay').fadeIn(2000, 'easeOutQuad');

});
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is the function you pass to beforeunload not being called?

Comment: Well after looking at it, it seems that it indeed is getting called. But I guess now I need to know how to set a interval so that the fade will show THEN navigate away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`beforeunload` events are unreliable, you cannot make sure they are fully executed, because the differences in unload speeds across browsers and computers.
Also, to achieve the fade-in effect, the unload must be delayed, which is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was playing around with trying to delay the unload but I guess that's not going to work.