# Detect back and forward buttons with JS

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have a site design where I want pages to do a fading transition as you navigate from page to page. I had a sophisticated method I was working out to use `jQuery.load` and hash tag urls and such. Then I realized that a much simpler solution could be achieved by simply intercepting link clicks, running a fade animation and then redirecting to the linked page (which is set to fade itself in). No need to use ajax and run everything from within one page.

I have just one small problem. If a user clicks forward or back buttons, or uses the keyboard to the same effect...how do I trigger the fade animation? I know you can use `jQuery('window').unload()` but then I don't know if I am going back or forward or just refreshing the page. This is critical because the fade animation actually needs to fade the background to match the page that it is going to.

Answer (score 2):

Simply hide body and then fadeIn :)

the key is on :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("body").css("display", "none");
            $("body").fadeIn(2000);
    });
```

You can see the follwoing links for more help:

[How to Use jQuery to Make Slick Page Transitions](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/)

[Page Fade In effect with Jquery](http://keycss.com/javascript/jquery/page-fade-in-effect-with-jquery.html)

First Link is better :)

---

**Edit**: you can see comments for more info, but my result is :

If you back to page using hotkeys, or `history.back()` or `history.forward()` maybe the `.fadeIn()` effect will not work again, you can try the following code to redo fadeIn effect :

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

But if you tried use :

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){
    $("body").fadeOut(2000);

});
```

or:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    $("body").fadeOut(2000);
});
```

the fadeOut will not work even the code syntactically is correct, after search, seemes that because:

> `beforeunload` events are unreliable, you cannot make sure they are
>   fully executed, because the differences in unload speeds across
>   browsers and computers. Also, to achieve the fade-in effect, the
>   unload must be delayed, which is not possible.

This quotation from answer of [Jquery, FadeIn before unload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569902/jquery-fadein-before-unload) .

Comment: That does not solve my problem. The first link, which I am already using some code from does nothing about handling forward and back action. The second link doesn't even deal with fading out at all. I need to intercept the forward/back request, get the background image of the page it is going to, fade the current page to that image and THEN resume the back/forward action.

Comment: Just still not fully understand what exactly you want, maybe you mean if i click back page will still hidden but i think you can solve it by .load(), or .unload() , but if you want to make delayed fadeIn try use .delay() http://api.jquery.com/delay/ !

If i had time, I would to try it for you :)

Comment: The problem with what I have currently is that when I press back or forward it instantly jumps to the other page. I can fade the newly loaded page in, but how do I fade the old page out before leaving it? I can interrupt the back or forward request and do the fade out but then I don't know what to do next, `history.back()` , or `history.forward()` ?

Comment: I tried to solve your problem, and I found thats no way to fadeOut your page when unload or "beforeunload", but to solve fadIn when you back to page, you should use "$(window).load()" instead of "$(document).ready()" , you can see the answer of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569902/jquery-fadein-before-unload

Comment: Well if nobody else can come up with a solution I will take your word for it. Thanks for trying it out yourself.

Comment: You are welcome :), I hope I found at least half of solution, if you found a solution let us know :)

Comment: @Moss may you choose best answer here :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is very [link](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-keyboard-events-example/) with live example for keyboards events, if you merge with @Al-Mothafar answer, it will be complete :)

> for back arrow    keyCode = 37
>   for backspace     keyCode = 8
>   for forward arrow keyCode = 39

Comment: The arrow keycodes only fire with the alt-key held down? Because it only moves forward/back if you press alt-arrow.